# Fetch a specific ID using Rally REST and curl

Tags: perl, rest, rally

I am new to rally REST.  I have used curl/perl/REST api for RTC, so am familiar with it but learned mostly by using examples. I need to be able to fetch a specific ID and the Name associated with it accessing it through curl and perl scripting. For example DE46835 Name:This is my defect.  I haven't found any examples to fetch just a known ID.  Can you point me to any documentation for this or provide an example how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the FormattedID you should be able to query using a URL like this:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?query=(FormattedID = "DE46835")

The full web service api documentation is available here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Comment: What if is not a defect? What if is a task, user story or anything else?

Comment: use the corresponding endpoint for that type- task, hierarchicalrequirement, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answer.  I was able to figure it out and get it to work.
Here is what I did.

$cmd = "curl -k -u \"${user}:${password}\" \"${url}\" -c ${cookies} -o ${auth}";
system($cmd);

Then

$cmd = "curl -k \"$url\" -o ${return} -b ${cookies}";
where $url=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?query=(FormattedID = "DE46835")